# Array pf promises return Script Uncaught error before promise.allSettled

Tags: javascript

I was pushing list of promises into an array, so that later i can use `promise.allSettled` to get result of promises but once i push promises to an array and after that i make an api call and then use `promise.allSettled` to get results of it, but it threw Uncaught promise first.

```
(async function () {
const fakeTimer = (val) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res(val), 2000))
const fakeTimerError = () => new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(() => rej('Hello'), 300))
var arr = [1, 2, 4, 6,7, 3]
var promises = []

try {
    for (let val of arr) {
        await fakeTimer('test1')
        if (val === 4) {
            promises.push(fakeTimerError())
        } else {
            promises.push(fakeTimer(val))   
        }
    }
    const res = await Promise.allSettled(promises)
    console.log(res)
} catch (error) {
    console.log('error', error)
}
})()
```

Response i am getting

[image: Image of response]

Comment: Can you explain what your final question is?

Comment: I want it should not through uncaught exception

Comment: Why are you doing `await fakeTimer('test1'); await fakeTimer('test2')`? You should call `Promise.allSettled` immediately after filling the array, which *handles* the promises in the array.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the function awaits before the promises are wrapped with `allSettled()`.  If you call `allSettled()` first it works fine.

```
const remaining = Promise.allSettled(promises)
await fakeTimer('test1')
await fakeTimer('test2')
const res = await remaining
```